# Alternative to nested for loop in R without all possible combinations

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

Imagine I have this bit of nested for loop, which prints all combinations of a and b

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(2,3,4,5)

for(i in a){
  for(k in b){
    print(i + k)
  }}
```

So the output looks like this

```
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

How do I loop through the two loops to get a result with only 4 items, the sum of elements from a and b with the same index, akin to looping through a dictionary in Python? I would like to have result like this:

```
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
```

or this

```
[1] 3 5 7 9
```

Whereby I simply add up a and b like adding up two columns in a dataframe to produce a third of the same length.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can just simply sum them: `a + b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, in `R`, mathematical operators such as `+` are `Vectorize`d. This means that by default you can feed them vectors as arguments and they will know how to walk through the elements in each input vector. Therefore simply doing `a + b` will give the desired result. If you really want to do this as a loop, then you can don't need to nest it - simply take a single index, `i`, to pull elements from both input vectors. Another option that might be helpful here is `purrr::map2()` which applies the specified function across two input lists.

However it's worth noting that if you **did** want to see all pairwise combinations, you could use the `outer()` function.

```r
# test vectors
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(2,3,4,5)

# operate pairwise through the two vectors
a + b
#> [1] 3 5 7 9

# go through vectors as a loop
for(i in seq_along(a)){
      print(a[i] + b[i])
}
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 5
#> [1] 7
#> [1] 9

# for more complex function can use purrr::map2 to run on two input lists
purrr::map2_dbl(.x = a, .y = b, `+`)
#> [1] 3 5 7 9

# operate on all combinations
outer(a, b, `+`)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    3    4    5    6
#> [2,]    4    5    6    7
#> [3,]    5    6    7    8
#> [4,]    6    7    8    9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes ofc I get that, just gave an very simplistic example because the original problem would be quite complicated to explain in detail.... But basically I would need to use a loop (or a function) to solve it, but do not need all possible combinations of a nested loop

Comment: Then perhaps your example was too simple to represent the critical aspects of your true problem. I just added a few more options, but if this doesn't solve your problem I suggest you make your example sufficiently complex to capture those critical elements.

Comment: yes you are correct. I basically need an equivalent of Python's zip() for looping through vectors in parallel in R (and not nested)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with python, but does the `zip()` function actually apply a function to the iterable arguments, or simply concatenate them into a list of tuples?

Comment: If you just want a list of tuples, you can do `purrr::map2(.x = a, .y = b, `c`)`

Comment: Thanks seq_along() was perfect for my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Try *mapply*:

```
mapply(`+`, a, b)
# [1] 3 5 7 9
```

We can replace `+` any other function, for example `paste` or `*`:

```
mapply(paste, a, b)
# [1] "1 2" "2 3" "3 4" "4 5"
mapply(`*`, a, b)
# [1]  2  6 12 20
```

In **R**, loops are wrapped into *apply functions, see:

- [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)